# Anaconda Navigator does not start on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, anaconda, linux-mint, navigator

Installed Anaconda on Linux Mint 19 as per the instructions. After installing I try to start the Anaconda Navigator via "anaconda-navigator".

It does not start and I get the error:

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable "DISTRO_NAME" referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

You can also just run `conda update anaconda-navigator` in terminal and run `anaconda-navigator` again. Worked for me I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing all again and updating conda, anaconda navigator and navigator updater

Answer (score 0):

For linux Mint users:

`file ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/vscode.py`

On line 159 after `if` statement and before `for` add  line `DISTRO_NAME='ubuntu'`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root`

I've found this method on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoBxbwbrZy0